# golang - how to route data from default port to another[4000] port

Tags: go

currently my go server is running on port 4000. to access web application i need to type `somedomainname:4000` in browser.

I would like to only type `somedomainname` and it should make the connection to web server on port 4000.

Comment: Have your Go server running on port 80.

Comment: @Volker,  currently Its on port 4000 not 80. i want to run its on port 4000 but need some type of mapping that if i enter domain name on browser it should make a request to port 4000

Comment: Try to use docker. You can run your server in docker container on port 4000 and make container to expose port 80

Comment: @Volker Don't run your web applications as root

Comment: @DanieleD: you don't need to run as root to use CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several solutions for this:

1. Have your Go server listen directly on port 80. However, be careful with how you implement this. **Do not have your service run as root**, but use Linux capabilities instead (thanks to @JimB who reminded me of this in comments). You can use `setcap` to grant a process the capability to bind to a privileged port:

   ```
   > setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/your/application
   ```
2. Use an HTTP reverse proxy like Nginx to forward all HTTP requests from port 80 to your Go application. Here's an example configuration file for Nginx:

   ```
   upstream yourgoapplication {
     server localhost:4000;
   }

   server {
     listen 80;

     server_name somedomainname;

     location / {
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

       proxy_pass http://yourgoapplication;
     }
   }
   ```

   When you do this, you can configure to Go application to listen on `127.0.0.1:4000` instead of `0.0.0.0:4000` to make your application accessible *only* by port 80.
3. If and when you are deploying your application in a Docker container, you can simply map the container port 4000 to the host port 80. [See the manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/) for more information.

Comment: 1 is incorrect. You can, and should run your server as an unprivileged user and still bind to 80, using linux capabilities. Use setcap and CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE. Don't use authbind, which was written 17 years ago before linux capabilities had this, which itself has been around for many many years.

Comment: Not to mention, authbind uses LD_PRELOAD to override the call to `bind`, which won't work with Go, because Go makes the syscall directly.

Comment: @JimB, thanks for the hint, I totally forgot about setcap. I've updated my answer accordingly and removed the reference to authbind.

Comment: If you want to be complete, instead of bringing in all of docker just to redirect a port, you can do this yourself with a simple iptables command. Iptables or capabilities are how sysadmins have been doing this long before docker existed.

Comment: @JimB, true. I actually intended my answer to be read as "In case you're using Docker anyway, you can also...", not as "Switch to Docker just for doing...". I'm aware this can also be done with iptables, however I would not be able to produce the config for that off the top of my head.